# iOS FBSDKLikeControl / FBSDKLikeButton cached like result?

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0, fbsdklikecontrol, fbsdklikebutton

I found out that the `FBSDKLikeControl` cached the like result.

When I click the Like control to like a page, I can verify from browser that the page is liked. The `FBSDKLikeControl` codes are as follow:

```
if(likeButton) {
    [likeButton removeFromSuperview];
    likeButton = nil;
}
likeButton = [[FBSDKLikeControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 150, 200, 50)];
likeButton.likeControlStyle = FBSDKLikeControlStyleStandard;
likeButton.likeControlHorizontalAlignment = FBSDKLikeControlHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
likeButton.objectID = @"https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers"; // FBID: 19292868552
likeButton.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:likeButton];
```

Then, I **unlike** the Page in browser and reload the view controller to make sure the like button is recreated, the Like Control still claims I liked the page.

How can I avoid the cache? The same situation happens in `FBSDKLikeButton`. Using `FBSDKShareKit 4.8.0` via Cocoapods

Comment: did you find any luck on this? I've faced this issue and still stuck with it for 2 days research but no luck.

Comment: Nope. Reported to Facebook, awaiting reply.